# .ToList() thread-safe

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I've have the following situation:

- There is only one thead which only adds items to a list
- Multiple threads which can read the items.

I know when we directly expose the list, I will ran into concurrent modification while enumerating.

But when I call `.ToList()` it makes a instance of the List and copies all items with the Array.Copy function of the .NET Framework.

What do you mean, is it safe when using this approach when dirty reads are ok?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new Container();
            Thread writer = new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    container.Add(new Item("Item " + i));
                }
            });

            writer.Start();

            Thread[] readerThreads = new Thread[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < readerThreads.Length; i++)
            {
                readerThreads[i] = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    foreach (Item item in container.Items)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                    }
                });
                readerThreads[i].Start();
            }

            writer.Join();

            for (int i = 0; i < readerThreads.Length; i++)
            {
                readerThreads[i].Join();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Container
    {
        private readonly IList<Item> _items;

        public Container()
        {
            _items = new List<Item>();
        }

        public IReadOnlyList<Item> Items
        {
            get { return _items.ToList().AsReadOnly(); }
        }

        public void Add(Item item)
        {
            _items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        private readonly string _name;

        public Item(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `synclock`?

Comment: Why don't you use a `ConcurrentBag` which is inherently thread safe?

Comment: @Christos `ConcurrentBag` is best used when the same thread is performing the reading and writing due to the fact that storage is implemented as thread local storage and has to do extra work to take items from another threads bag if the local collection is empty. If you are using multiple threads use `ConcurrentQueue` instead. See [When to Use a Thread-Safe Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment (+1). I wasn't aware of this :(.

Comment: It's only the question if it's dangerous, when dirty reads are ok and a solution without locks. 
ConcurrentBag is unordered and does not implement `IList<T>`

And I don't want to make my domain model dirty with syncs and locks, or do you?

Comment: @crip Are you aware your current implementation will likely print `Item 0` 10 times and may never print `Item 999`, is this the behavior you wanted? This behavior has nothing to do with thread safety and would still do it even if you used dasblinkenlight's thread safe implementation in his answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In c# , how to iterate IEnumerable in multithreading environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403020/in-c-sharp-how-to-iterate-ienumerable-in-multithreading-environment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is it safe when using this approach when dirty reads are ok?

Easy answer - no, it's not.

First, the method does not guarantee that by definition. Even if you look at the current implementation (which you should not do), you'll see that it's using `List<T>` constructor accepting the `IEnumerable<T>`. Then it checks for `ICollection<T>` and if yes, uses `CopyTo` method or just iterates the enumerable. Both are unsafe, because the first one relies on the (unknown) implementation of `CopyTo` method while the second will receive exception when (the standard behavior) the collection enumerator is invalidated during the `Add`. And even if the source is a `List<T>` and is using the `Array` method you mentioned http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,d2ac2c19c9cf1d44

```
Array.Copy(_items, 0, array, arrayIndex, _size);
```

still is unsafe because it may call copy with `_items` and `_size` beyond the `_items.Length` which of course will throw exception.  Your assumption would have been correct only if this code is somehow getting both members atomically, but it doesn't.

So, simple don't do that.

**EDIT:** All above applies to your concrete question. But I think there is a simple solution for the situation you have explained. If single thread add/multiple thread read with acceptable stale reads is the requirement, then it could be achieved by using the `ImmutableList<T>` class from the `System.Collections.Immutable` package like this:

```
public class Container
{
    private ImmutableList<Item> _items = ImmutableList<Item>.Empty;
    public IReadOnlyList<Item> Items { get { return _items; } }
    public void Add(Item item) { _items = _items.Add(item); }
}
```

Comment: That's the anwser I'm was looking for, Thanx Ivan!

Comment: You welcome. I've added some thoughts at the end which you may find useful.

Comment: Yes. We also had the idea with ImmutableList, but it introduce a lot of refactoring. 

The problem was that we have known that's an issue in multithreaded environment, so we created a test which should reproduce the issue...but no exceptions occured. ...hmm and that's why we looked at the implementation in .NET source an we wasn't shure if Array.Copy does some internal trick.

We use lock() now, because we have no real timing issues. Maybe we can go with ReadWriterLockerSlim.

Thx again.

Answer (score 4):

What I would do is ditch your current implementation and switch to a [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new BlockingCollection<Item>();
    Thread writer = new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            container.Add(new Item("Item " + i));
        }
        container.CompleteAdding();
    });

    writer.Start();

    Thread[] readerThreads = new Thread[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < readerThreads.Length; i++)
    {
        readerThreads[i] = new Thread(() =>
        {
            foreach (Item item in container.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        });
        readerThreads[i].Start();
    }

    writer.Join();

    for (int i = 0; i < readerThreads.Length; i++)
    {
        readerThreads[i].Join();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What a `BlockingCollection` will do is give you a thread safe queue (By default it uses a `ConcurrentQueue` as the backing storage, you can change the behavior to a stack by passing a `ConcurrentStack` to the constructor) that will block the `foreach` loops on the readers when the queue is empty waiting for more data to show up. Once the producer calls `container.CompleteAdding()` that lets all of the readers stop blocking and exit their `foreach` loops.

**This does change your program's behavior**, your old way would have given the same `Item` to multiple threads, this new code will only give the item inserted to a single "worker" thread. This implementation will also give new items to workers that where inserted in to the list after the worker entered its `foreach` loop, your old implementation uses a "Snapshot" of the list and does its work on that snapshot. I am willing to bet this is the behavior you actually wanted but you did not realize your old way would have duplicated the processing.

If you did want to preserve the old behavior of multiple threads all using "snapshot in time" lists (multiple threads process the same item, new items added to the list after the snapshot are not processed) switch to using the `ConcurrentQueue` directly instead of the `BlockingCollection`, it's `GetEnumerator()` creates a "moment in time" snapshot of the queue when you create the enumerator and will use that list for the `foreach`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new ConcurrentQueue<Item>();
    Thread writer = new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            container.Enqueue(new Item("Item " + i));
        }
    });

    writer.Start();

    Thread[] readerThreads = new Thread[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < readerThreads.Length; i++)
    {
        readerThreads[i] = new Thread(() =>
        {
            foreach (Item item in container)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        });
        readerThreads[i].Start();
    }

    writer.Join();

    for (int i = 0; i < readerThreads.Length; i++)
    {
        readerThreads[i].Join();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is not thread-safe, despite the fact that you are returning a brand-new copy of your list each time the `Items` property is accessed.

Consider this situation:

```
Container c = new Container();

// Code in thread1
c.Add(new Item());

// Code in thread2
foreach (var item in c.Items) {
    ...
}
```

When the call to `c.Items` is made, the `_items` list is enumerated inside `ToList()` in order to construct a copy. This enumeration is not different from an enumeration that you would perform yourself. Just like your enumeration, this enumeration is not thread-safe.

You could make your implementation thread-safe by adding a lock object, and locking it when adding to the container or when requesting a copy of the items in the container:

```
public class Container {
    private readonly IList<Item> _items;
    private readonly synclock = new object();

    public Container() {
        _items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Item> Items {
        get {
            lock (synclock) {
                return _items.ToList().AsReadOnly();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(Item item) {
        lock (synclock) {
            _items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the `ToList()` does not enumerate internally. Instead Array.Copy is used from .NET which calls a `internal static extern Copy` method from the CLR. No Exeptions occours. And `Array.Copy` is static method which should be thread-safe by design.

That's why im asking...

Comment: static != thread safe (if the data passed into it is shared across threads, you run into issues) @crip

Comment: @crip Although the current implementation appears to do it in a thread-safe way, there is no guarantee that it is going to remain that way, because there is no explicit mentioning of this in the documentation. Moreover, your code becomes very fragile if you rely on this implementation. Consider what would happen if someone decides to replace `_items = new List<Item>();` with `_items = new LinkedList<Item>();`